# Excluding the first 3 characters of a string using regex

Tags: regex, bash, sed

Given any string in **bash**, e.g flaccid, I want to match all characters in the string but the first 3 (in this case I want to exclude "fla" and match only "ccid"). The regex also needs to work in **sed**.

I have tried positive look behind and the following regex expressions (as well as various other unsuccessful ones):

```
^.{3}+([a-z,A-Z]+)
sed -r 's/(?<=^....)(.[A-Z]*)/,/g'
```

Google hasn't been very helpful as it only produce results like "get first 3 characters .."

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you show us the context code, even with the regex that doesn't work, that would help.

Comment: Do you want to use the regular expression in `bash` (`[[ $str =~ $regex ]]`) or in `sed`, or with some other tool? Your question is too vague at the moment.

Comment: I am currently stuck on getting it to work with sed, sorry for the vagueness , I will edit the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get *all characters but the first 3* from a string, you can use `cut`:

```
str="flaccid"
cut -c 4- <<< "$str"
```

or bash variable subsitution:

```
str="flaccid"
echo "${str:3}"
```

That will strip the first 3 characters out of your  string.

Answer (score 1):

You may just use a capturing group within an expression like `^.{3}(.*)` / `^.{3}([a-zA-Z]+)` and grab the `${BASH_REMATCH[1]}` contents:

```
#!/bin/bash
text="flaccid"
rx="^.{3}(.*)"
if [[ $text =~ $rx ]]; then
        echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]};
fi
```

See [online Bash demo](https://ideone.com/oX6XXy)

In `sed`, you should also be using capturing groups / backreferences to get what you need. To just keep the first 3 chars, you may use a simple:

```
echo "flaccid" | sed 's/.\{3\}//'
```

See [this regex demo](https://ideone.com/oMZCoa).  The `.\{3\}` matches exactly any 3 chars and will remove them from the beginning only, since `g` modifier is not used.

Now, both the solutions above will output `ccid`, returning the first 3 chars only.

Comment: Well, your question sounds ambiguous, do you need `fla` or `ccid` from `flaccid`? Please let know so that I could adjust the answer. Note that in Bash you *match* with `=~` and capture what you need. In `sed`, you capture what you need and match what you do not need, then use backreferences to the groups what you need to keep.

Comment: title says exclude first 3 characters... and question has `all characters **but** the first 3` so `ccid` is expected output I believe... lot of questions could do with SO forcing ppl to include sample input and output (with ability to remove them when needed)

Comment: @Sundeep: Good, thanks, I "synchornized" the two solutions. Aha, now the questions says *in this case I want to exclude "fla" and **match only "ccid"***, so now the answer is correct.

Comment: Bounds like `{3}` are part of POSIX regular expressions; they are not a Perl extension. (In a basic regular expression, you need to escape the braces like so: `\{3\}`, but `{3}` is valid in an extended regular expression.)

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew I have updated the question to be more clear - I want to exclude the first 3 characters of any string, so in my example string I want to match `ccid`.

Comment: @chepner: `{3}+` is definitely not POSIX, POSIX does not support possessive quantifiers. Of course `{min,max}` *is* POSIX-compatible.

Comment: I updated the sed solution so now it looks very simple and easy to understand and use.

Answer (score 0):

Using sed, just remove them

```
echo string | sed 's/^...//g'
```

Answer (score 0):

How is it that no-one has named the most simple and portable solution:
shell "Parameter expansions":

```
str="flacid"
echo "${str#???}
```

For a regex (bash):

```
$ str="flaccid"
$ regex='^.{3}(.*)$'
$ [[ $str =~ $regex ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
ccid
```

Same regex in **sed**:

```
$ echo "flaccid" | sed -E "s/$regex/\1/"
ccid
```

Or sed (Basic Regex):

```
$ echo "flaccid" | sed 's/^.\{3\}\(.*\)$/\1/'
ccid
```